# How to cast a generic type without knowing the type

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a generic object in runtime. So far I have been able to create it but I can't figure out how to cast it. What I have is the enum object and I want to generate the EnumMapper that converts the enum value to custom string to map to a legacy database.

```
Type enumType = myEnum.GetType();
Type enumMapperType = typeof(EnumMapper<>)
                      .GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(enumType);
var mapper = Activator.CreateInstance(enumMapperType); // OK
EnumMapper<> mapper = (EnumMapper<>) Activator.CreateInstance(enumMapperType); // Error
```

When I inspect the object in the debugger it is create as I expect, but how can I cast it so I can use it?

The class:

```
public class EnumMapper<T> : IEnumMapper<T>
```

The interface:

```
public interface IEnumMapper<T>
{
    T EnumValue(string value);

    bool HasEnumValue(string stringValue);

    bool HasStringValue(T enumValue);

    string StringValue(T enumValue);
}
```

---

```
Error   2   ; expected  \EnumMapperTest.cs  36
Error   4   ; expected  \EnumMapperTest.cs  36
Error   1   Invalid expression term '>' \EnumMapperTest.cs  36
Error   3   Invalid expression term '>' \EnumMapperTest.cs  36
Error   34  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement  \EnumMapperTest.cs  36
Error   36  The name 'mapper' does not exist in the current context \EnumMapperTest.cs  36
Error   35  Using the generic type 'EnumMapper<T>' requires 1 type arguments    \EnumMapperTest.cs  36
Error   37  Using the generic type 'EnumMapper<T>' requires 1 type arguments    \EnumMapperTest.cs  36
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: I'm sure there are duplicates of this... but could you give us more information about what you're trying to achieve with the instance, and whether or not you're in control of the generic type? (For example, could you create a non-generic base type?)

Comment: EnumMapper<> - what`s a type?

Comment: Error - Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: @Jon, can you add the link?

Comment: In which way you want to use this EnumMapper<> later? maybe you may cast it to some less specific, like untyped IList or IEnumerable?

Comment: @uncletall: No - I haven't found an *exact* duplicate yet, although the are plenty of *similar* questions listed down the right hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the exact thing you need is not possible in C#. Basically, you need for a method to have different types or the returned variable, based on the value of a regular, non-generic, parameter, i.e. if the parameter is `typeof(Enum1)`, than the result variable is `EnumMapper<Enum1>` and if the parameter is `typeof(Enum2)`, than the result variable is `EnumMapper<Enum2>`.

You can do this with generic parameters, however, since generics is all about compile-time information, and you only have the value at runtime, they cannot be used in this case.

What you can do (and what I have done) is to use dynamic code to work around this problem, being careful to go into statically-typed land as soon as possible (dynamic is really contagious, some say like a smile, some say like a virus):

```
public dynamic GetMapperObject(Type enumType)
{
  Type enumMapperType = typeof(EnumMapper<>)
                           .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                           .MakeGenericType(enumType);
  var mapper = Activator.CreateInstance(enumMapperType);
  return mapper;
}
```

with calling code like:

```
var mapper = GetMapperObject(enumType);
//dynamic call, bind the resut to a statically typed variable
bool result = mapper.HasEnumValue("SomeStringValue")
```

---

(old answer, just adds another level of indirection to the problem :) )

You could wrap all that in a generic method, something like this:

```
public EnumMapper<T> GetMapperObject<T>()
{
  Type enumType = typeof(T);
  Type enumMapperType = typeof(EnumMapper<>)
                           .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                           .MakeGenericType(enumType);
  var mapper = Activator.CreateInstance(enumMapperType);
  return mapper as EnumMapper<T>;
}
```

and invoke it with

```
var mapper = GetMapperObject<EnumMapperTestEnum>();
```

However, if you only have a single value for the enum, you can use type inference, something like:

```
//everything is the same, just different signature
public EnumMapper<T> GetMapperByExample<T>(T item)
{
  Type enumType = typeof(T);
  Type enumMapperType = typeof(EnumMapper<>)
                           .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                           .MakeGenericType(enumType);
  var mapper = Activator.CreateInstance(enumMapperType); // OK
  return mapper as EnumMapper<T>;
}
```

and call it with type inference

```
var mapper = GetMapperByExample(EnumMapperTestEnum.SomeValue);
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not have T, I get an enum and then want to create an enum mapper for this enum...

Comment: This works if you replace your code with the call, and extract the method.

Comment: Ok, I guess my question is not clear. I do not have the type T, only enumType. This is just for test purpose that I do the typeof(T)

Comment: Ok, that works.... now my problem is that I have more level of indirection as I get my enum also from reflection.

Comment: :) I Agree, I misunderstood the problem. I know I've solved a similar problem I had a while ago, just to see if I can find if it's relevant to this situation.

Comment: Seems like I am still stuck with the chicken and egg

Comment: Accepted your answer, that works. In the end I actually went to change the interface to a non-generic type. I thought that was a bit more readable for me...