# Cast an object with a generic type without knowing the type

Tags: c#, linq, generics

According to the following object definitions:

```
public interface IMessage
{
    Guid Identifier { get; set; }
}

public class Message : IMessage
{
    public Guid Identifier { get; set; }
}

public interface IEventMessage<TPayload> : IMessage
{
    TPayload Payload { get; set; }
}

public class EventMessage<TPayload> : Message, IEventMessage<TPayload>
{
    public TPayload Payload { get; set; }
}

public interface ICommandMessage<TParameters> : IMessage
{
    TParameters Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class CommandMessage<TParameters> : Message, ICommandMessage<TParameters>
{
    public TPayload Payload { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to filter a collection of Messages according to their type without taking into account their generic type

```
var messages = new List<IMessage>
{
    new CommandMessage<string>() { Name = "Command Message String" },
    new CommandMessage<int>() { Name = "Command Message Int" },
    new EventMessage<string>() { Name = "Event Message String" },
    new EventMessage<int>() { Name = "Event Message Int" }
};

var onlyStringCommandMessages = messages.OfType<CommandMessage<string>>();  // OK
var onlyIntCommandMessages = messages.OfType<CommandMessage<int>>();        // OK
var onlyCommandMessages = messages.OfType<CommandMessage<object>>();        // KO
var onlyCommandMessages2 = messages.OfType<CommandMessage<dynamic>>();      // KO
```

I have tried other techniques such as:

```
var onlyCommandMessages3 = messages.Where(x => 
  x.GetType()
  .GetInterfaces()
  .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && (i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandMessage<>)))); // OK but return IMessage types
```

It seems to work but it returns me IMessage types. How can I cast to ICommandMessage at the same time?

It would be very useful to have a `any` type like in Typescript. `ICommandMessage<any>`

I have found [another subject related to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186391/how-to-cast-a-generic-type-without-knowing-the-type) but it doesn't help me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about just creating a non-generic version of `IEventMessage` and `ICommandMessage` that the generic versions inherit from?

Comment: At some point, that's what I do. But at a higher lever (library), I need to process different kind of messages regardless their generic type. The only thing that matter is their "main" type (Event, Command, ...)

Comment: What should be the result of the query? If you transform your issue to a `List<T>`, you cannot say `List<> anyList = yourQuery.ToList()`. You need the generic type parameter. A `List<string>` is something different than a `List<int>`. The same is true for your  `ICommandMessage<T>`.

Comment: While you could filter on these generic types, the outcome could only be cast to `object`. If you need to access the *non-generic part* you have to create an additional non-generic interface and filter on that. If this is not intended or possible, than you have to write either some reflection code or use `dynamic` (for the whole type, not only the generic parameter).

Comment: You're dealing with a class structure that doesn't quite suit your needs. Clearly, you need a logical way to access all `CommandMessage` objects (regardless of any generic parameter), yet your code does not contain such a type to begin with. That just means that you need to re-evaluate your design so it can include such a type. What that type looks like very much depends on what you aim to do with it. So, after you've fetched your `CommandMessage` objects, what are you doing to want to do with them? Anything involving their generic property? Or something else that doesn't rely on it?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you ask, but (inspired by [IEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator) and [Enumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1)`<T>`) you use a non generic interface like :

```cs
public interface ICommandMessage : IMessage
{
    object Parameters { get; set; }
}

public interface ICommandMessage<TParameters> : ICommandMessage
{
    TParameters Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class CommandMessage<TParameters> : Message, ICommandMessage<TParameters>
{
    public TParameters Parameters { get; set; }
    object ICommandMessage.Parameters
    {
        get => Parameters;
        set => Parameters = (TParameters)value;
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```cs
var onlyCommandMessages = messages.OfType<ICommandMessage>();
```

Edit from @Flater comment :

With this structure, you have no guarantee the class that implement `ICommandMessage<TParameters>` will return the same object to `ICommandMessage<TParameters>.Parameter` and `ICommandMessage.Parameter`. It's the same problem with `IEnumerator<T>`.

Like @Flater suggest, you can minimize `ICommandMessage` to correspond your need.

Comment: Assuming OP isn't interested in accessing the parameters themselves (given that they don't care about the type of those parameters to begin with), it'd be better to just make `ICommandMessage` an empty marker interface. It allows for the same distinction, without a dirty and prone-to-bad-practice `object Parameters` property.

Comment: You are right. Create a ICommandMessage interface without the generic parameter does the trick. Even if I do not really like an empty interface. Anyway, I still have other issues... I conclude that my design is faulty and I need to change it. Thank you all